# There is no IOS certificate with ID xxxxxxxxxx on this team

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3, provisioning, ios-provisioning

In Xcode:

**Organizer > Devices**

then on the *left*
**Library > Provisioning Profiles**

Click **Refresh** in the bottom right - this runs fine

Click **Renew** on a provision that is soon to expire. I end up getting a prompt that says: "There is no IOS certificate with ID 'xxxxxxxxxx' on this team."

Of course the message contains a real ID, I just blotted it out with Xs instead.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deleting and renewing the profile a number of times it finally just worked. At this point I'm happy again so I'm not in the mood to ask any questions..

## Important

I had deleted and created the profile I needed in Xcode a number of times, but it only worked after I re-made it again inside the online provision portal.

Comment: Delete everything from Xcode preferences and on developer.apple.com. Then go to the project's general settings and click the "Fix issue" button complaining about no team profile. That's what I did.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem.  I called Apple for support.  They referred me to following these instructions: 
https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html
heading: How do I delete/revoke my certificates and start over fresh?

I was concerned about following those instructions, but was assured by this statement in the instructions:
"Important: Members of the Standard iOS Developer Program can be assured that replacing either your developer or distribution certificate will not affect any existing apps that you've published in the iOS App Store, nor will it affect your ability to update those apps."

Answer (score 2):

Deleting and re-adding AppleIDs from Xcode preferences is what helped me.